# kubectl create: how to refer to storageclass defined in separate yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying to launch a service using minikube, with several YAMLs I have.

pod.yaml is main yaml to launch pod. It contains:

```
volumes:
      - name: my-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-data
```

In pod.yaml, I also see:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-data
  annotations:
   productName: "...."
spec:
  accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
  storageClassName: "local-path"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

I see that 'local-path' is defined in another yaml(storage.yaml), like this:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-path
provisioner: rancher.io/local-path
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

To launch pod:

> kubectl create -f pod.yaml

This results in 'local-path' not found message.

So how do I pass storage.yaml to this command? Or some other way of bringing storage.yaml in play?

PS: Running 'minikube kubectl -- apply -f storage.yaml' before running pod.yaml got rid of the issue.

Comment: If you're using Minikube, it already has a [storage provisioner](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#dynamic-provisioning-and-csi); you should be able to delete the StorageClass and the `storageClassName:` reference from the PersistentVolumeClaim.